# How do I call retrofit along with greendao for post request?

Tags: android, api, android-studio, retrofit, greendao

I am trying to integrate greendao with the retrofit. This link will give an idea ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qmbu.jpg) of how the data is sent to the server. It is a post request and I am really confused about how to call this request via retrofit.

It will be really helpful if someone can help me with it.

In API response I am getting an request object, response object, message and status code.

response object I have fields about the user and in request object I have field about the information that is being send.

another picture here 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5DBz.jpg

Comment: you can POST JSON object with `@Body` attribute of `Retrofit`

Comment: @AliAhmed I have done that but still, it is showing an error. please check i have added another picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create response like this using this method

```
private String create(String email, String password) {
    try {
        JSONObject cell1 = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

        cell1.put("email", email);
        cell1.put("password", password);

        jsonObject.put("data", cell1);

        return jsonObject.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Call you POST as this

```
@FormUrlEncoded 
@POST("your_path_here") 
Call<String> uploadData(@Body String obj);
```

in your Activity

```
String json = create("your_email", "your_password");

apiInterface.uploadData(json).enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: it is giving an error "@Body parameters cannot be used with form or multi-part encoding. (parameter #1)". what should i do now ?

Comment: problem is solved - rather than using body i used field to sent the json object and got my result. Thanks for your help.